# Very Minor Car Collision with No Damage, Hit Car Left

Tags: criminal-law

Today, I tapped another car on the highway. The driver got out, and I immediately asked if he was okay. He said he had a bloody lip but that he was otherwise okay. we checked the cars for property damage but found none. He also checked his work laptop and it worked still. He then looked at me, nodded, and said "Drive Safe." We both got back in our cars and I anticipated exchanging information, but he drove off. The police were, of course, never called. To the best of my knowledge, he has no information about me.

Obviously this is a fantastic break for most people and a relief. However, I am wondering if there is any possible liability on my end. He was the one who left the accident scene unprompted, and I sat there bewildered. Perhaps he lacked auto insurance or had some ulterior motive for leaving. He seemed rushed. Regardless, should I report this as a cover-your-ass? And what are my risks for doing so or not doing so?

This took place in Illinois.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

He broke the law by leaving the scene without exchanging information.[1](http://www.criminallawyerillinois.com/2010/02/19/what-are-the-penalties-for-leaving-the-scene-of-an-accident-in-illinois/)

Since there was bodily injury ("a bloody lip"), both drivers are required to report the accident.

Comment: Link is no longer working btw

Comment: The legislature is kind enough: license suspended, http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/fulltext.asp?DocName=062500050K11-406

Comment: It does not make sense he would have a bloody lip as a result of a collission if there was no visible damage between 2 cars. Cars are designed to absorb damage to protect the occupants - I would expect any accident involving enough force to cause even minor injury would result in visible damage.

Comment: @davidgo A pretty minor accident with just the slightest tap can do enough to cause a pretty minor injury.

Comment: @davidgo the act of breaking ot try and prevent the collision would cause in passengers getting rocked and causes injury. Contact of cars indicates breaking was not enough.